# How to get youtube metadata while playing using video.js 7

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, video.js

Video.js provides a method to get video metadata such as player.duration(). This works for regular mp4 videos. Is it possible to get information about license and title of YouTube videos?

Answer (score 0):

You may check in this [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) the list of parameters that this query (`Videos: list`) supports.

> The `part` parameter specifies a comma-separated list of one or more `video` resource properties that the API response will include.
>
> If the parameter identifies a property that contains child properties, the child properties will be included in the response. For example, in a `video` resource, the `snippet` property contains the `channelId`, `title`, `description`, `tags`, and `categoryId` properties. As such, if you set `part=snippet`, the API response will contain all of those properties.